# Selecting rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r, sampling

Consider the following data set.

```
id var1 var2
1   A   33
2   B   23
3   A   45
4   A   55
5   B   22
6   A   33
7   B   90
8   A   78
9   B   12
10  A   11
```

I want to take a random sample (rows) of size `5` and `4` from `A` and `B` category, respectively. Can one help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sample`:

```
sample_1 <- sample(df[df$var1 == "A", ]$var2, 5)
sample_2 <- sample(df[df$var1 == "B", ]$var2, 4)
```

Use `replace=TRUE` for sampling with replacement.

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text="id var1 var2
1   A   33
2   B   23
3   A   45
4   A   55
5   B   22
6   A   33
7   B   90
8   A   78
9   B   12
10  A   11", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to `split` the dataset and use `sample` in `Map`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(dat, y)
   dat[sample(seq_len(nrow(dat)), size = y),], split(df, df$var1), c(5, 4)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:10, var1 = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A"), var2 = c(33L, 23L, 45L, 55L, 22L, 33L, 90L, 
78L, 12L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```